# My react native app logouts on every refresh in feathersjs

Tags: mongodb, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, feathersjs

I am using react native with feathersjs and having issue of being logout after every refresh on app after some changes.

```
const client = feathers();
options = {
    header: 'Authorization', // the default authorization header for REST
    prefix: '', // if set will add a prefix to the header value. for example if prefix was 'JWT' then the header would be 'Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi...'
    path: '/authentication', // the server-side authentication service path
    jwtStrategy: 'jwt', // the name of the JWT authentication strategy 
    entity: 'user', // the entity you are authenticating (ie. a users)
    service: 'users', // the service to look up the entity
    cookie: 'feathers-jwt', // the name of the cookie to parse the JWT from when cookies are enabled server side
    storageKey: 'feathers-jwt', // the key to store the accessToken in localstorage or AsyncStorage on React Native
    storage: AsyncStorage
  }

client.configure(auth(options))
```

```
export const checkAuthorization = () => dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt').then(r => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CHECK_AUTHORIZATION', payload: r });
     return client.passport.verifyJWT(r);
        }).then(payload => {
            dispatch({ type: 'JWT_PAYLOAD', payload: payload })
            return client.service('users').get(payload.userId);
        }).then(user => {
            client.set('user', user);
            client.get('user').then(user => {
                dispatch({ type: 'PROFILE', payload: user })
            })
        })
    .catch(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'AUTHORIZATION_FAILED' })
    })
```

i want to keep the app signed in untill unless i myself signout it.

Comment: and by refresh do u mean reloading of application ?

Comment: @sohaibkarim yes.

Comment: did you try to check if ` AsyncStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt')` gets the token?

Comment: @Jalil yes it returns an accessToken